# C++ Boost::thread invoking a c function - Facing compilation error

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, boost, boost-asio

Have to invoke a C static function as part of my boost worker thread function.The C static function works as part of other C++ code however, it fails to compile  while being part of a worker thread function.

Following is the list of headers included in my C++ header file.

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <queue>
```

and c code header starts as follows

```
    #ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C" {
    #endif

    #if defined(MS_WINNT) || defined(WIN32)

    #include <windows.h>
    typedef BSTR     ARG;
```

I don't have a control over the C code but have a control over C++ code that I'm invoking.

Error message I'm experiencing is as follows

> error C2146: syntax error : missing ';'

However, if I reverse the order of include files, I get a different error message.

> error C1189: #error :  WinSock.h has already been included

Using visual studio 2010 with boost 1.62 libraries. Is it possible to compile and run this sort of stuff?

Adding primary section of C++ code.

```
#ifndef  _THREADS
#define  _THREADS
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <queue>

namespace testThreads
{


    class boostthreads
    {
            boost::asio::io_service _io_service;
            boost::asio::io_service::work _work;
            boost::thread_group _Threads;
            std::queue<std::string> _queueOfRequests;
            boost::mutex _mutex;

            void handleCurrentRequest();
            unsigned long getThreadId ( std::string& currentThreadIdA);


    public:
            boostthreads();
            ~boostthreads();
    };

}
#endif
```

Comment: Could you show the code snippet where C2146 occurs?

Comment: Added the code. That was the C++ header file. The C header file beginning was given already. Either order doesn't work. (C++ header file followed by C Header file or vice versa).

Comment: I need to see the line where "syntax error : missing ';'" occurs to make a guess what's wrong.

Comment: The syntax error is happening in typedef BSTR     ARG; ( Which is included in the header file of the library that was shipped). I'm not allowed to modify the header file of the library.

Comment: Looks like the library header assumes that windows.h is included before it. Try to include WTypes.h before your C header.

Comment: In the previous comment I meant include wtypes.h instead of windows.h, that may be enough.

Comment: Amazing. Thanks for the response. Can you please post this as an answer and can close the question. How did WTypes.h solve the issue of BSTR?

Comment: The error at "typedef BSTR ARG" was because BSTR wasn't defined at this point. I think your C header assumes that Windows.h should be included before it. WTypes.h is included somewhere inside Windows.h. However Windows.h also includes WinSock.h which conflicts with including of WinSock.h inside of boost/asio.hpp. However looks like BSTR is the only thing your C header was needed from Windows.h, so you just had to include WTypes.h to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the discussion in the post comments we found that C2146 error occurred because BSTR typedef definition is required in your C header. Including of Windows.h before the C header leads to conflict due to double include of WinSock.h by both Windows.h and boost/asio.hpp. However BSTR is the only thing your library needs from Windows.h, so the solution is to include just the header where BSTR is defined. This header is WTypes.h. Just FYI, BSTR on Microsoft docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/automat/bstr